# Black space on screen Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile

I make a simple snake on windows and i need to check current head position on screen. In desktop this works perfect but on phone i got a little problem because i got some black margin/space ? on screen and it doesn't calculate perfect.

Is there any way to check this black space size, or disable this space ? [image]

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Answer (score 0):

To fix that, i need to enable full screen mode.